# Set the presence of a keyword or words as a condition for scraping information form a web page

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I would like to search a web page for certain keywords and key phrases and set their presence as a condition for proceeding to parse the page and extract content fields. Can anyone suggest a solution?

In general, I think the code would look something like:

```
# All the preceding information for the spider
(imports, class declarations, rules etc.).

if response.xpath('//*[contains(/text(), 
"some keyword" or "some key phrase" or "some other keyword")]')
   def parse_items (self, response):

# All the subsequent information for the spider
```

I'd like to know whether I'm on the right track and, if so, how to proceed. Alternatively, I'd be interested in completely different approaches to setting the presence of keywords as a precondition to the extraction of data with Scrapy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this questions shall be closed since it's both too broad and opinion based. However here's a suggestion:

In Python and `scrapy` we don't do things like this:

```
if something_happens:
    def parse_items (self, response):
        do_something()
```

Instead, we do it like this:

```
def parse_items (self, response):
    if something_happens:    
        do_something()
    else:
        # Do other things or nothing.
        pass
```

Also, although I think this question shall not be posted in StackOverflow, you could still find help from other parts of the [Scrapy community](http://scrapy.org/community/). The IRC channel and mailing list shall be good place
for asking such questions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback starrify. I figured out the order issue with the conditional statement myself through trial and error. Specifically, the following worked for me:
    def parse_items (self, response):
        items = []
        descriptors = response.xpath('the path to the section I would like to search')
            for item in descriptors:
                if response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "key word")]'):
                # paths to retrieve info for fields go here
                else:
                   pass